# Same weights, implementation but different results n Keras and Pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, pytorch

I have an encoder and a decoder model ([monodepth2](https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2)). I try convert them from Pytorch to Keras using `Onnx2Keras`, but :

- Encoder(ResNet-18) succeeds
- I build the decoder myself in Keras (with `TF2.3`), and copy the *weights* (numpy array, including weight and bias) for each layer from Pytorch to Keras, without any modification.

But it turns out both `Onnx2Keras`-converted Encoder and self-built Decoder fails to reproduce the same results. The cross-comparison pictures are below, but I'd first introduce the code of **Decoder**.

First the core Layer, all the conv2d layer (`Conv3x3`, `ConvBlock`) is based on this, but different dims or add an activation:

```
# Conv3x3 (normal conv2d without BN nor activation)
# There's also a ConvBlock, which is just "Conv3x3 + ELU activation", so I don't list it here.
def TF_Conv3x3(input_channel, filter_num, pad_mode='reflect', activate_type=None):

    # Actually it's 'reflect, but I implement it with tf.pad() outside this
    padding = 'valid'  

    # if TF_ConvBlock, then activate_type=='elu
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filter_num, kernel_size=3, activation=activate_type,
                                  strides=1, padding=padding)
    return conv
```

Then the structure. Note that the definition is EXACTLY the same as the original [code](https://github.com/nianticlabs/monodepth2/blob/ab2a1bf7d45ae53b1ae5a858f4451199f9c213b3/networks/depth_decoder.py#L17). I think it must be some details about the implementation.

```
def DepthDecoder_keras(num_ch_enc=np.array([64, 64, 128, 256, 512]), channel_first=False,
                       scales=range(4), num_output_channels=1):
    num_ch_dec = np.array([16, 32, 64, 128, 256])
    convs = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(4, -1, -1):
        # upconv_0
        num_ch_in = num_ch_enc[-1] if i == 4 else num_ch_dec[i + 1]
        num_ch_out = num_ch_dec[i]

        # convs[("upconv", i, 0)] = ConvBlock(num_ch_in, num_ch_out)
        convs[("upconv", i, 0)] = TF_ConvBlock(num_ch_in, num_ch_out, pad_mode='reflect')


        # upconv_1
        num_ch_in = num_ch_dec[i]
        if i > 0:
            num_ch_in += num_ch_enc[i - 1]
        num_ch_out = num_ch_dec[i]
        convs[("upconv", i, 1)] = TF_ConvBlock(num_ch_in, num_ch_out, pad_mode='reflect')  # Just Conv3x3 with ELU-activation

    for s in scales:
        convs[("dispconv", s)] = TF_Conv3x3(num_ch_dec[s], num_output_channels, pad_mode='reflect')

    """
    Input_layer dims: (64, 96, 320), (64, 48, 160),  (128, 24, 80), (256, 12, 40), (512, 6, 20)
    """
    x0 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(96, 320, 64))
    # then define the the rest input layers
    input_features = [x0, x1, x2, x3, x4]

    """
    # connect layers
    """
    outputs = []
    ch = 1 if channel_first else 3
    x = input_features[-1]
    for i in range(4, -1, -1):
        x = tf.pad(x, paddings=[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')
        x = convs[("upconv", i, 0)](x)
        x = [tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D()(x)]
        if i > 0:
            x += [input_features[i - 1]]
        x = tf.concat(x, ch)
        x = tf.pad(x, paddings=[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [0, 0]], mode='REFLECT')
        x = convs[("upconv", i, 1)](x)
    x = TF_ReflectPad2D_1()(x)
    x = convs[("dispconv", 0)](x)
    disp0 = tf.math.sigmoid(x)

    """
    build keras Model ([input0, ...], [output0, ...])
    """
    # decoder = tf.keras.Model(input_features, outputs)
    decoder = tf.keras.Model(input_features, disp0)

    return decoder
```

The cross-comparison is as follows... I would really appreciate it if anyone could offer some insights. Thanks!!!

Original results:

[image]

Original Encoder + Self-build Decoder:

[image]

ONNX-converted Enc + Original Dec (Texture is good, but the contrast is not enough, the car should be very close, i.e. very bright color):
[image]

ONNX-converted Enc + Self-built Dec:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Solved!

It turns out there's indeed no problem with implementation (at least not significant ones). It's the problem with `weights` copying.

The original weights has (H, W, 3, 3),  but TF-model requires dim of (3, 3, W, H), so I permuted it by [3,2,1,0], overlooking the (3, 3) also have their own sequence.

So it should be `weights.permute([2,3,1,0])`, and all is well!